# Make changes to a file and write it back?

Tags: python, replace

I have a file which looks like the following:

```
# exchange        1
 1     -1.00      0.00 -52602.05    277.00    277.00      0.00      -1
 2      1.00      0.00 -52557.77    279.00    281.00      2.00      -1
 3      1.00      0.00 -52578.18    281.00    279.00      0.00      -1
# exchange        2
 1      1.00    279.71 -52651.48    277.00    279.00      1.00      -1
 2     -1.00    282.11 -52551.07    281.00    281.00      0.00      -1
 3      1.00    274.73 -52507.33    279.00    277.00      1.00      -1
 ...
# exchange      161
 1     -1.00    310.63 -50702.48    313.00    313.00      0.48      -1
 2     -1.00    294.27 -51919.85    291.00    291.00      0.36      -1
```

I want to add a constant (like 10) to the third value of the line with the pattern "# exchange" so that:

```
# exchange      1
```

would become:

```
# exchange      11
```

throughout the whole file and save the changes in the original file.

I have come up with following to make the changes but I don't know how to save the changes.

```
data_1  = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
lines_1 = data_1.readlines()
data_1.close()

for line in lines_1:
    p = line.split()
    if p[0] == "#" and p[1] == "exchange":
    a = int(p[2])
    print('p',int(p[2]))
    a += 100
    p.insert(2,a)
    print('p now',p[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re` module (`re.sub`) to replace the lines with `# exchange <number>`.

For example (`file.txt` contains your text from the question):

```
import re

CONSTANT = 10

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line = re.sub(r'^(#\s+exchange\s+)(\d+)', lambda g: g.group(1) + str(int(g.group(2))+CONSTANT), line)
        # print the line
        print(line, end='')
```

Prints:

```
# exchange        11
 1     -1.00      0.00 -52602.05    277.00    277.00      0.00      -1
 2      1.00      0.00 -52557.77    279.00    281.00      2.00      -1
 3      1.00      0.00 -52578.18    281.00    279.00      0.00      -1
# exchange        12
 1      1.00    279.71 -52651.48    277.00    279.00      1.00      -1
 2     -1.00    282.11 -52551.07    281.00    281.00      0.00      -1
 3      1.00    274.73 -52507.33    279.00    277.00      1.00      -1
 ...
# exchange      171
 1     -1.00    310.63 -50702.48    313.00    313.00      0.48      -1
 2     -1.00    294.27 -51919.85    291.00    291.00      0.36      -1
```